# Fortnite Creative Barriers

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Is it possible to make barriers in creative disappear after a certain time limit? Im doing this because i am trying to make a capture the flag mode where you have 5 minutes to construct a base, then the barriers drop and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a guide to show how to make a capture the flag map in Fortnite Creative

This should help you make a great Fortnite Creative mode Capture the Flag game. Although this may not use barriers, it is a great map for a simple hide and seek game.